# Keep text in the textbox when open and close the app

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have created an app where users can store their passwords in iv used an image which is an icon and then a textbox next to it and also a login system and logout button. When the user types in the textbox and logouts out when they log back in the textbox is empty.

So far for my other textboxes I have put search in the textbox and when the users clicks the textbox it disappears and the comes back again now I just need to figure out how to keep the text in the textbox unless the user deletes it themselves.

I'm not sure if its simple by using one of the events.

Comment: So? you have a textbox > user signs in > types in textbox > logouts > signs back in > !!and now text is gone?!! 
What exactly happens when you logout? Does it close the form? What happens when you login? Does it create a new form? Does the form load the data after the user logs in? Does the form even save the data from the textbox when the user logs out?

Comment: the user signs in and it opens a new form which has a number of textboxs on and then the logout button just closes the form. I'm not sure how to get the data to be saved or loaded again after the user logins.

Comment: You will have to persist the value elsewhere. I highly recommend not doing this for passwords, though.

Comment: Alright, simple fix. Look up some tutorials on file writers and file readers for c#. Once you understand the concept, you can implement it into your form. Once a user logs in, load the content, etc. And Ginosaji is right, never ever store passwords as plain text... ever.

Comment: This is a prototype so real passwords arent actually going to be stored I will look into the file writers and file readers

Answer (score 1):

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  // Read the data...
      {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("f:\\hg.txt");

        textBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd().ToString();
        sr.Close();

    }


    StreamWriter sw;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // write the data in the txt file
    {

            sw = new StreamWriter(textBox2.Text);

            sw.WriteLine(textBox3.Text);


            sw.Close();


        }
```

I am try solve your problem. I paste two button and two textboxs. i have faced the problem when i writing in English Language.

Comment: In the basic sense, this solves your problem for saving a loading data, just make sure you know how you are going to load it and format it.

Comment: ok will research this as currently dont know anything about it.